# TableView cell not updating after Selecting item using delegate Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, appdelegate

I am trying to implement delegate method for selection item. I am getting confuse in updating tableView cell. As I have multiple sections and list would be one which will use for different cells. How can I update my tableview cell row or model so I reload tableView?

Model:

```
struct Unit : Codable {

    let sectionList : [SectionList]?

}
struct SectionList : Codable {

    let title : String?
    let items : [Item]?

}

struct Item : Codable {

    let actionType : Int?
    let actionUrl : String?
    let bgColor : String?
    let booleanValue : Bool?
    let textField : String?
    let textValue : String?
    let unitId : Int?
    let latitude : Double?
    let longitude : Double?
    let actionParamData: String?
    let actionTitle: String?
    let pickList: [SectionList]?
    let multiSelect: Bool?
    let selectedValue: [String]?
    let version: Int?
    let masterId: Int?
    let itemValue: String?
}
```

FirstViewController:

```
var AppData: Unit?

func listFunc(tvc2: ViewController, didSelectList listValue: String) {
        print(listValue)
        let indexPathRow:Int = 0
        let indexPosition = IndexPath(row: indexPathRow, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPosition], with: .none)
    }
```

SecondViewController: (contains list)

```
protocol ListDelegate {
    func listFunc(tvc2: ViewController, didSelectList listValue: String)
}
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!
        //print(currentCell.textLabel?.text as Any)
        currentCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        delegate?.listFunc(tvc2: self, didSelectList: currentCell.textLabel?.text ?? "")

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)


       }
```

Comment: Where do you set the first view controller as the delegate of the second?  Why do you always reload row 0?

Comment: @Paulw11 set delegate in `secondViewController`. `var delegate: ListDelegate?`

Comment: @Paulw11 Actual simple scanero is I have to select any item from `secondViewController` and want to set in `FirstViewController`. Once item selected it refresh cell.

Comment: That's where you delcare the delegate but you need to set your instance of your first view controller to that property somewhere

Comment: @Paulw11 I am really new into this and get confused that how to set? Can I share my `github` link to you any possibility?

Comment: You need to set the delegate where you present the second view controller (typically in `prepareForSegue`). Also you need to unwind back to your existing first view controller,not present a new instance e

Comment: In fact, you probably, don't need a delegation pattern. You simply update the items selection state in your data model and then reload the tableview in `viewWillAppear` of your first vc

Comment: @Paulw11 Can I share code? actually I tried but not achieved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You are bit confused that how delegate works. Here I am modifying your code.
Suppose your have two viewControllers i.e `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` now what you want is send back data or reload data from `SecondViewController` to `FirstViewController`. So what you need to do is create a `Protocol` on `SecondViewController` and confirm that `Protocol` in `FirstViewController`. Below is example of your code:

> FirstViewController

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewControlller, ListDelegate {

   var selectedIndex: Int?
   var selectedSection: Int?

   //Click event for navigation from FirstViewController to SecondViewController
   @IBAction func BackButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
       let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
       vc.delegate = self
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }

   func listFunc(listValue: String) {
       AppData?.sectionList?[selectedSection!].items?[selectedIndex!].textField = listValue
       tableView.reloadData()
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       //Add these two line in your code
       selectedIndex = indexPath.row
       selectedSection = indexPath.section
   } 
}
```

> SecondViewController

```
protocol ListDelegate {
    func listFunc(listValue: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewControlller {
    var delegate: ListDelegate?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!
        //print(currentCell.textLabel?.text as Any)
        currentCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        delegate?.listFunc(listValue: currentCell.textLabel?.text ?? "")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   }
}
```

> Response.swift

```
//Change let to var for these
var textField : String?
var textValue : String?
```

Above code might be resolve your issue. Please try this code. `Happy To Help`

Comment: Thank you :) it's working now. One thing more to know how can I reload tableview / model for these changes ?

Comment: @NewBieMobile `listFunc` method in `FirstViewController` will help to reload your tableView.

Comment: Yes it not reloading tableView data. Same data exist on selection.

Comment: Okay I get the issue. To reflect your new value in tableViewCell you need to hold it in another variable and then assign it in `cellForRowAt: index` method or you can update your data model directly in `listFunc` method.

Comment: Thank you , Here is the link. https://github.com/MasamMahmood/SqliteDataList

Comment: Is the link accessible? please confirm and I think data model approach would be fine because once its reflected I will re-post updated values to server.

Comment: Yeah, it's accessible.

Comment: I have made some changes in your code but unable to push to code.

Comment: Actually its full public repository all permissions I have already given

Comment: I have updated my answer here, take a look and change accordingly.

Comment: Thank you perfect all done. I have updated that one: `AppData?.sectionList?[selectedSection!].items?[selectedIndex!].textValue = listValue`   
A small issue left only if I click on upper cell row it changes only last index row section not change that one which I clicked.

Comment: Thank you Shiv for your support. I fixed it :)

Comment: Can I ask one question its related to post parameters as I am struggling with passing model as a parameter to alamofire.? Please ...